# In Android : How to retrieve all phone numbers and all email(primary , work, other) of all my contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I need to retrive all contacts with **all phone numbers** , email ids in a json object like(sample single contact object) :

```
[{
    "id": 123,
    "displayName": "Name",
    "company": "Company",
    "title": "Title",
    "numbers": [{
        "type": "home",
        "number": "957842"
    }, {
        "type": "work",
        "number": "54654654"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "number": "465454"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "number": "5465431"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "number": "54321"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "number": "6546545"
    }],
    "emails": [{
        "type": "home",
        "email": "asd@gmail.com"
    }, {
        "type": "work",
        "email": "asdas@gmail.com"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "email": "asdasd@gmail.com"
    }, {
        "type": "other",
        "email": "sdasdmail.com"
    }]
}]
```

Snippet from my current code looks like :

```
String searchQuery = "_id  > " + lastReadId;
            Cursor contactUrl = cContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,searchQuery,null,"_id ASC");
            Log.e(TAG, "getContact >> " + contactUrl.getCount());
            while (contactUrl.moveToNext())
            {
                objChild = new JSONObject();
                String name=contactUrl.getString(contactUrl.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String number=contactUrl.getString(contactUrl.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                int phoneContactID = contactUrl.getInt(contactUrl.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
                int phone_type = contactUrl.getInt(contactUrl.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                objChild.put("name",name);
                objChild.put("number",number);
                objChild.put("phone_type", number);
                Log.e(TAG, "objChild : " + objChild.toString());
```

My current contact is like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNuWH.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs8Qk.png

Whatever code I got in stackoverflow was giving me single phone number of contacts or multiple contacts which have multiple numbers(I can manipulate same but it will take good time and may lead to performance issue)

**My requirement is to get all phone numbers & emailids of a single contact.**

Comment: is this `JSON` direct from url or you are fetch it from some website database...

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Comment: Hi @ChintanRathod :
Appriciate your reply , but my concern is not json , my concern is of fetching all numbers of contact. e.g I can add 200 numbers and emails in same contact. I need all those info. Can you please check for this ?

Comment: @Mohit : This json I have made manually in which I want to format my contacts. My issue is not with json strucure but fetching contacts data.

Comment: can you please show in your code where you are parsing json..i mean have to tried simple json parsing and getting string out of it..[link](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-Example/blob/master/src/com/example/jsonexample/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in your project for easy JSON parsing

**Step 1**

Open **[jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)** website.

**Ste 2**

Copy/Paste your JSON string in given space and select below options to use with Gson.

- Enter packagename and classname as per your requirement
- select JSON as source type
- select Gson as annotation style

[image]

**Step 3**

Click on ***Preview*** button to get ready made classes. Copy paste full classes in your application. Else you can also select ***jar*** to get classes.

**Ste 4**

Download and Add Gson library to your project

Download Gson : [google-gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

**Step 5**

Final step. Write below short line of code to convert JSON string to class objects

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<PersonBean> details = gson.fromJson(strJsonData, PersonBean.class);
```

References :

- https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
- https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Hi Chintan,
Appriciate your reply , but my concern is not json , my concern is of fetching all numbers of contact. e.g I can add 200 numbers and emails in same contact. I need all those info. Can you please check for this ?

Comment: @SunnyKhanuja This will give you list of persons with list of numbers and emails. List<Email> and List<Number> will be generated after parsing with this technique. Atleast try once.